# Change domain in entry.url

Tags: entries, entry, search

I have a group website which has a main site and 3 sub sites all within 1 Craft Installation.
Each sub site has its own Structure Section for Content.

I am adding a Group Wide Search to the main site and sub sites.
Sub sites are accessed by subdomain of main site - e.g.  property.domain.com agents.domain.com

On a sitewide search if I get results from the subsites the entry.url will just contain the domain from the site it is being searched for.

So for my search results - I will check the handle of the entry to see if it is from the subsites - and then if possible replace the domain.

I can get the handle with:

```
{% set handle = entry.section.handle %}
```

Is there a handy way to replace the domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Craft/Twig `|replace` filter, which supports [regex](http://regexr.com/) replacements.

Something like:

```
{% set handle = entry.section.handle %}

{% if handle == 'subSiteSectionHandle %}
    {% set newUrl = entry.url|replace('/regexMatchPattern/', 'replacedWith') %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: great - works 100% - using {% set newUrl = entry.url|replace(craft.request.serverName, 'newhostname') %}